# Npgsql AddWithValue doesn't work with transaction

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, npgsql

I am attempting to execute a query with a transaction in Npgsql as it make the code significantly cleaner and more consistent with queries in other systems with pure SQL. However I get the error `Npgsql.PostgresException: 42703: column "_hash" does not exist` on the following code.

```
var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(@"
do
$do$
begin
    if ((select count(1) from components where hash = @_hash) = 0) then
        insert into components (hash, name) values (@_hash, @_name);
    end if;
end
$do$", db); // db is NpgsqlConnection connection
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_hash", "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_name", "t_test");
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // error on this line
```

The following does work for some reason which make me think that it is an issue with AddWithValue in Transactions

Hard coding the values;

```
var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(@"
do
$do$
begin
    if ((select count(1) from components where hash = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') = 0) then
        insert into components (hash, name) values ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', 't_test');
    end if;
end
$do$", db);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Getting rid of the transaction

```
var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("insert into components (hash, name) values (@_hash, @_name);", db)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_hash", "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_name", "t_test");
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

What is causing this issue and how can it be fixed?

NOTE: I can run the query which is failing in a database manager like JetBrains DataGrip so the query is not malformed.

Comment: Why don't you use `insert into ... where not exists ..`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass parameters to an anonymous `do` block. It is not related to npgsql but to Postgres.

The [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) says:

> The code block is treated as though it were the body of **a function
>   with no parameters**, returning void. It is parsed and executed a single
>   time.

Comment: Thank! Just for any future reference, due to that limitation I did the (mildly) unsafe work-around of making an extension method on NpgsqlCommand which just does a find and replace with some logic to detect the type and format it properly to emulate the functionality.

Comment: For this specific example, an `upsert` with `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` would work very nicely, and it is in a single transaction